# Grand Central Dispatches - execution out of order?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to get a better understanding of GCD so I wrote the test code below (Bottom).  Essentially two functions with waits inside sent on different queues and println on main thread waiting for particular tasks.

I expect the console output should be:

```
BEFORE FUNCTIONS
start 3 sec loop
start 5 sec loop
end 3 sec loop
BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG
AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG
end 5 sec loop
BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER
AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER
```

but what I get instead is:

```
BEFORE FUNCTIONS
start 3 sec loop
start 5 sec loop
BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER
AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER
end 3 sec loop
BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG
AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG
end 5 sec loop
```

a number of things don't make sense to me - 1.  Why are the "Longer" ones printed before the "Long"?  2.  Why are the "Longer" ones not printed after the *END* of the longer i.e. 5 second function?

#### CODE (ViewController.swift)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  var longQueue = dispatch_group_create()
  var longerQueue = dispatch_group_create()
  var queueLow = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)
  var queueHigh = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
  
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("BEFORE FUNCTIONS")
    
    dispatch_async(queueHigh) {
      self.longFunc()
    }
    
    dispatch_group_notify(longQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG")
    }
    dispatch_group_notify(longerQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER")
    }
    
    dispatch_async(queueLow) {
      self.longerFunc()
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(longQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG")
    }
    dispatch_group_notify(longerQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER")
    }
  }
  
  func longFunc () {
    dispatch_group_enter(self.longQueue)
      println("start 3 sec loop")
      sleep(3)
      println("end 3 sec loop")
    dispatch_group_leave(self.longQueue)
  }
  
  func longerFunc() {
    dispatch_group_enter(self.longerQueue)
      println("start 5 sec loop")
      sleep(5)
      println("end 5 sec loop")
    dispatch_group_leave(self.longerQueue)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two categories of problems here:

1. You are entering the dispatch groups *inside* the `longFunc` and `longerFunc`. But, because you're dispatching the calls to those functions to their respective queues, you have no assurances that you're going to reach `dispatch_group_enter` before you reach the `dispatch_group_notify` calls you perform in `viewDidLoad` on the main thread. Also remember that the code that is dispatched to the background queues runs asynchronously and we have no assurances when it runs versus the code that is continuing to execute on the main thread. The key is that if it encounters `dispatch_group_notify` before you've even entered the group, that notify closure will fire immediately.

   To avoid this race condition, you either want to perform the `dispatch_group_enter` in `viewDidLoad` before you dispatch the code to the background queues (and obviously, before you set up the notify closure), or you want to just retire the entering and leaving of the groups and then replace `dispatch_async` with  `dispatch_group_async`. Either of those approaches ensure that you enter groups before you add the notify closures to those groups.
2. The dispatch notify closure that reports "BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER" is an even more egregious example, where there's not even a race condition. You are simply adding that notify closure before you even dispatch the function that will later enter the group. So this will almost certainly fire before you code is dispatched to that queue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I did not know the dispatch_group_notify(queueX) block would just execute if queueX is not setup yet.  Thinking about it, I guess a non-existant queueX is potentially similar to an empty queueX (not sure how GCD deals with finished queues).  I've tried both your suggestions - placing the dispatch_group_enter before the dispatch_async as well as switching to dispatch_group_async (cleaner).  Both result in expected output (BETWEEN WAIT ON LONGER still fires first but understandably so).

Answer (score 0):

When you queue a block using `dispatch_async`, there may be some time before that block begins running, during which the queueing thread (the main thread, in your case) continues to run. Then again, the queued block may begin running right away, before the next statement in the queueing thread runs.

When you call `dispatch_group_notify`, if the group's entry count is zero at that moment, `dispatch_group_notify` will immediately queue the notification block for execution. But queuing a block for execution is different than running the block! If the dispatch queue is busy, it won't run the notification block right away.

Let's look at how (I deduce) things happened to produce your actual output. After each statement that had some important effect, I'll describe what it did. I'll also put the print actions in bold.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("BEFORE FUNCTIONS")
```

**That line printed `BEFORE FUNCTIONS` to standard output.**

```
    dispatch_async(queueHigh) {
      self.longFunc()
    }
```

You queued `longFunc` to run on `queueHigh`. It began running immediately and called `dispatch_group_enter` on `longQueue`, raising `longQueue`'s entry count to 1. **It also printed `start 3 sec loop`.** Then it went to sleep for 3 seconds. It's on a background thread, so this didn't block the main thread.

```
    dispatch_group_notify(longQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG")
    }
```

You submitted a notification block to print `BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG` when `longQueue`'s entry count is zero. It's not zero right now, because `longFunc` entered but hasn't left yet, so the notification block is added to the group, not to the main queue.

```
    dispatch_group_notify(longerQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER")
    }
```

You submitted a notification block to print `BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER` when `longerQueue`'s entry count is zero. It's zero now, because `longerFunc` hasn't even been queued yet, so the notification block is immediately added to the main queue. But the main thread is busy running this method (`viewDidLoad`) right now, so it can't drain the main queue yet.

```
    dispatch_async(queueLow) {
      self.longerFunc()
    }
```

You submitted `longerFunc` to `queueLow`. It doesn't start running right away.

```
    dispatch_group_notify(longQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG")
    }
```

You submitted a notification block to print `AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG` when `longQueue`'s entry count is zero. It's not zero right now, because `longFunc` entered but hasn't left yet, so the notification block is added to the group, not the main queue.

```
    dispatch_group_notify(longerQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      println("AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER")
    }
```

You submitted a notification block to print `AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER` when `longerQueue`'s entry count is zero. It's zero now, because `longerFunc` hasn't started yet, so the notification block is immediately added to the main queue. But the main thread is busy running this method (`viewDidLoad`) right now, so it can't drain the main queue yet.

```
  }
```

You returned from `viewDidLoad`, which lets main thread continue execution of the main run loop. Here's what happened next:

- `longerFunc` started running. It called `dispatch_group_enter` on `longerQueue`, raising `longerQueue`'s entry count to 1. Note that this does not retroactively remove those notification blocks from the main queue! They were queue at a time when `longerQueue`'s entry count was zero, and they will remain on the main queue until they run, regardless of what happens to `longerQueue`'s entry count later.
- **`longerFunc` printed `start 5 sec loop`** and then went to sleep for 5 seconds. This is on its own background thread, so it doesn't block the main thread or the thread running `longFunc`.
- The main thread's run loop dequeued a block from the main queue and executed it. This was the first notification block you submitted for `longerQueue`. **It printed `BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER`.**
- The main thread's run loop dequeued another block from the main queue and executed it. This was the second notification block you submitted for `longerQueue`. **It printed `AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONGER`.**
- The main thread's run loop didn't find any more blocks waiting on the main queue. It went to sleep.
- The `longFunc` function finished its 3 second sleep. **It printed `end 3 sec loop`.**
- The `longFunc` function called `dispatch_group_leave` on `longQueue`. This lowered the entry count of `longQueue` to zero, so the group submitted all pending notification blocks to the main queue. This act woke up the main thread's run loop.
- The main thread's run loop dequeued another block from the main queue and executed it. This was the first notification block you submitted for `longQueue`. **It printed `BETWEEN FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG`.**
- The main thread's run loop dequeued another block from the main queue and executed it. This was the second notification block you submitted for `longQueue`. **It printed `AFTER FUNCTIONS WAIT ON LONG`.**
- The main thread's run loop didn't find any more blocks waiting on the main queue. It went to sleep.
- The `longerFunc` function finished its 5 second sleep. **It printed `end 5 sec loop`.**
- The `longerFunc` function called `dispatch_group_leave` on `longerQueue`. This lowered the entry count of `longerQueue` to zero. The `longerQueue` group had no pending notification blocks, so it did nothing.

The end.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed run through it helps to explain things.  One question though:  After the "}" in viewDidLoad you mention longFunc and longerFunc running on the main queue.  Aren't those running on queueHigh and queueLow respectively?

Comment: I don't think I said they run on the main queue. I said the main thread continues execution of the main run loop. The function run on their own threads, which I mention when I say they went to sleep for 3/5 seconds.